# ViewPager with Fragments holding GridView

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with two Fragments , each Fragment has a GridView

Frag1.java

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment{
GridView grid;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    grid = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    grid.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());

}

private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int ar []={R.drawable.ch1,R.drawable.ch2,R.drawable.ch3,R.drawable.ch4};
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ar.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return ar[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View v = view;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(v == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, viewGroup, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.img.setBackgroundResource(ar[i]);
        return v;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView img;
    }
}
```

Frag2 is the same as Frag1 but with two different things

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
}
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int ar []={R.drawable.gmc1,R.drawable.gmc2,R.drawable.gmc3,R.drawable.gmc4};
     ......
   }
```

This is SecondActivity which contain the ViewPager

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(fm);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

 class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment frag;
        if (position == 0) {
            frag = new Frag1();
        } else {
            frag = new Frag2();
        }
        return frag;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The problem is ViewPage view only one page (Frag2) and when scroll the page it get a blank page
[image]    [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird...

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    grid = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    grid.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());

}
```

Why are you looking for gridView in Activity? Probably you should do this in your onCreateView without messing in onActivityCreated

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
        grid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        grid.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
        return rootView;
}
```

**Some explanation:**

You are calling

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
```

which is searching in Activity in your ViewPager (and as it is extended ViewGroup) in its childrens (fragment layouts). Both are calling gridView1, assuming this grid is attached only to Frag1, you are creating Frag1 with this view and setting Adapter with ch drawables. Then second fragment Frag2 is created, get from Activity GridView inflated earlier in Frag1 and still present on the screen (alive, not null) and set gmc adapter