# Design a Grid view with categories and load images on demand in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview

I want to create a grid view similar to the image shown below. The category panel 
can be scrolled horizontally and has a list of items. When clicked on a category the grid view is loaded dynamically and selected category is underlined/highlighted. Grid also loads images on scroll vertically as well.

Currently, I download a xml with images to a gridview and use Picasso library to load images.

What I want to know is

1) how to add the categorizing to my current implementation?

2) Do I load a single xml with categories and image list first and then load images after or do I keep a xml per category.

3) How do I manage the grid adapter when user clicks on different categories

4) How do I design the category scroll view at top?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after reading the question  thoroughly your not asking for a Solution, your asking a Suggestions !! 
So, i come up with some approaches to guide you regarding the implementation.

As you mentioned in your question, you have different different categories and each of the category having the grid of images. one main hing is like you can select the category / you can swipe the grid view to change another category in your app.

Why not, these all you can do. Did you used [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html) & [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) ?

by combination of Using [ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/screen-slide.html) you can achieve the [same](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/) what your planning.

Here i am explaining  you in details >>

1. your category size is fixed ?

   if yes you can make static fragments for those. if it is not fixed in a size / order then you can create [PageAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) with the list of your categories and set that adapter to your view pager in home screen
2. Now you have a categories, After that you can create a corresponding fragment activity to hold a gridview and based on the page adapter position you can load the categories into the gridview
3. Here your all fragments having the same gridview, so you easily control it by using vie pager and respective gridview loading and controls you can made in the fragment.
4. By using this, there is no way of creating such no of xml files & classes as you mentioned in the question. It is a simple and easy way to handle

   5. The big advantage in this approch is like, you no need to bother about the size of categories (as your making as adapter, 35,50,100 that number go's on) it will add the categories to your view pager
   6. fragment loading also you can make a single fragment and re-use the same in all over application as every category having the same grid view .

Here is a sample [example](http://www.programering.com/a/MDN3AjNwATA.html) to use the fragments with gridviews in a view pager and [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Also you can find a lot of examples in SOF  like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962891/viewpager-with-fragments-holding-gridview)..

if you find any difficulty then come with a piece of code/trail what you did and ask in SOF.

Let me if any clarifications required.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Buy Xml I meant the dataset to load in the view (Category list and image url data) not the layouts. This means the view can have unknown number of categories till the xml data set is downloaded. For example Only the ALL category would be there at start and upon receiving data other categories would come in to play. Can you please give me steps I have to follow for this?
BTW I am doing this inside another fragment